# App crashes on simulator. Works on iphone device

Tags: iphone, crash, ios-simulator

I recently upgraded to Xcode 3.2.4. and started experiencing strange behaviour.

When I deploy my app onto the iPhone, it works fine.  However, when I deploy this on the simulator for testing, the app does not even start on the screen and I receive the following error:

---

[Session started at 2010-09-14 00:01:26 -0400.]
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1472) (Wed Jul 21 10:53:12 UTC 2010)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Attaching to process 33399.
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
warning: check_safe_call: could not restore current frame

warning: Unable to restore previously selected frame.
warning: Unable to restore previously selected frame.
warning: Unable to restore previously selected frame.
warning: Unable to restore previously selected frame.
warning: Unable to restore previously selected frame.
warning: check_safe_call: could not restore current frame

warning: Unable to restore previously selected frame.
warning: Unable to restore previously selected frame.
warning: Unable to restore previously selected frame.

---

I am at loss and have tried to run this in Instruments using the allocation and leaks tool, but it doesn't even have the chance to collect statistics since the simulator crashes first.  I've also tried to enable zombies as well, but it does work since the app does not even start up.

Is there any other way for me to diagnose what is happening here?

Thank you,
Winston

Comment: Have you tried removing the app from de simulator and try again ?

Comment: I also did just try that, but it appears to be the same.  I will try to create a new project and import the files to see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

You are certain the app debugs normally, with Xcode or Instruments, when on the device? The Simulator's state might be corrupted, or maybe just your app's state on the Simulator. A quick way to nuke and pave: choose the "Reset Content and Settings..." option from the iPhone Simulator menu. I've had to do this on a couple of occasions myself.

Comment: That was a good thought and I wasn't aware of that option to do so.  I did try it, but it still did not seem to work, I went to "Reset Content and Settings" and after clicking it, I didn't receive any confirmation, but believe it did do so.  I've also confirmed that debugging on the device does work.  I am going to create a new project and import file by file to see where it may have gone wrong and will update accordingly.  Any other ideas are appreciated!  Thank you.