# App crashes on simulator but runs fine on iPod 3.1.3. The Super class' init method is not being hit (even at debug) when app runs in simulator

Tags: iphone, crash, ios-simulator

All this might look too trivial but read it through -

I have simple class (A) and super class (B). I have init methods on both (designated initializer initWithData for A and regular (id)init for B) . I have a delegate defined on my super (B) which is called by [instanceofA setDelegate:self]. And of course I have following line of code - `@interface A:B { //declarations }`

So when I run my app on iphone simulator (Ver 3.2) the call to set Delegate the run fails with message "-[A setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4c59e10" and therefore the app crashes

When I debug my app, the [super init] call within initializer for A doesn't call its super i.e. B (even if I keep a debug pointer within B's init method)

**All this works absolutely fine if I run the app on my iPod (SDK 3.1.3)** - even the debug points are hit

For some reason, at run time the simulator is not able to find class A's super class that is B.

I have already tried resetting "Contents and Settings" on my iPhone Simulator but in-vain. I have also tried rebuilding multiple times, marked all my classes "touched". Nothing is working. Is this issue with cleaning the existing targets? How do we clean targets in XCODE?

I am not sure if its relevant but slightly similar issue is under discussion here -
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706068/app-crashes-on-simulator-works-on-iphone-device][1]

**Update!**

I know the problem - please ignore all the super int stuff above. The issue is with this message (which shows upfront on my debugger console - not as warning though) -

> objc[34514]: Class Connection is implemented in both /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.1.3.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message and /Users/admin1/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/3.1.3/Applications/xxxyyyyzzzzbbbbb/MyApp.app/MyApp. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

so i remove  "messageUI.framework" and remove all my references to it in my code like MFMailComposeViewController, canSendMail etc. and everything is back to normal. I should have known, that was my last set of implementations. I wasn't really doing any unit testing and therefore didn't realize this when I started testing my app.

I googled ofcourse and bumped into following url - groups.google.com/group/objectiveresource/tree/browse_frm/month/2009-07/d8b3f3664c39785b?rnum=1&_done=%2Fgroup%2Fobjectiveresource%2Fbrowse_frm%2Fmonth%2F2009-07%3F

which links to -
groups.google.com/group/objectiveresource/browse_thread/thread/349756a5e01eb8b1/8712f5fde9e9b47c?lnk=gst&q=prefix#8712f5fde9e9b47c

What are class name related guidelines for objective C? Any online resource (apple/non apple) which talks about how to avoid class name collisions? For now I will try to figure out which class of mine is causing this conflict...

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but if I were you, I would start by trying to understand why it is that the [super init] call within A is not calling B's initializer.  

In particular, suppose you set a breakpoint in your debugger just before that call, then step into it.  What happens?

Comment: The simulator and the device also use different versions of the runtime. This can also cause some fun issues at times.

Comment: To really clean all targets, use the finder to delete your build directory.

Comment: @william - yea i tried stepping in from A's int but it didn't step into B's int. Also thanks others for the advices specially @Joe - i didn't really knew that stuff! Actually, I have figured out the actual problem now but no solutions yet - please see above my updated Question

Comment: @Joe - That is incorrect.  LLVM works for both Simulator and device, although the 4.1 SDK had a bug that required you to add a compiler flag to prevent some compile-time errors.  See this question for more on that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677879/strange-issue-after-upgrading-to-ios-4-1-sdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to your revised question, Objective-C lacks namespaces, which is why you see collisions like what happened in your case.  This is why it is a convention to use two- or three-letter prefixes before your custom class names (something like SBHConnection would have avoided this problem in your case, for example).

See the question "[What is the best way to solve an Objective-C namespace collision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178434/what-is-the-best-way-to-solve-an-objective-c-namespace-collision)" for a detailed discussion about this, although that veers off into more technical territory.  See Scott Stevenson's [Cocoa Style for Objective-C](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000082.php) for a more down-to-earth explanation of some of the elements of style that you'll commonly see in Cocoa and Cocoa Touch applications.

Answer (score 0):

**it's Class named "Connection" in my class and also in messageUI.framework.. i should be reading stuff more closely!!**

Answer was right there in front of me all the time!! i guess it always is ...